# Excessive Boost Converter Output

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, boost

I'm implementing a boost switching regulator based on a Texas LM5002 chip ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5002.pdf21)), to get about 65V from a 12V supply. The design I've arrived at is shown below, inspired both from the data on the datasheet and the information [here](http://www.simonbramble.co.uk/dc_dc_converter_design/boost_converter/boost_converter_design.htm). I was not able to get all the parts with the necessary values, but I used the closest values I got my hands on. The design took into account an input current of about 50 mA to supply about 1mA on the output node.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq3sgs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Problem is, when I tie 12V to the input, I get, for a few seconds, around 900V (???), before the output shorting to ground. What is exactly could be causing this? Have I got something wrong on my circuit?

EDIT: It appears I made a mistake on my original question while drawing the schematic, the actual value of R4 is 1.6k and not 100 ohms.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT - in case any other potential downvoters miss the point - the original question had R4 as 100 ohms and asked if there was something wrong on the schematic (it now says "circuit")!!

It looks like R4 is the wrong value i.e. far too low. It forms a potential divider with R3. With the values shown it has an attenuation of 0.00124. In normal operation you would expect to see 1.26V at the FB (feedback) pin. With your attenuator this implies a line output voltage of about 1,017 volts.

Here's an example from the data sheet for a 48 volt output: -

[image]

Note the ratio of resistor values surrounded by the red rectangle. They attenuate by a factor of 38.35 and with 48 volts on the output, the voltage on FB is 1.252 volts. Given that it should be 1.26 volts (according to the data sheet) I reckon this circuit will produce 48.3 volts.

Comment: I made a mistake whe  drawing the above schematic. R4 is actually 1.6k.

Comment: You asked if there was something wrong with your schematic and this I identified.

Comment: The 10mH inductor used for energy storage seems might high - if this inductor has a self resonant frequency close to 1MHz (your switching speed) bizarre voltages could also be generated. I would definitely check this out and/or increase RT to something more manageable like sub-100kHz operation.

Comment: I'm not sure what the SRF of this particular inductor is, but looking at similar parts on several catalogs makes me believe it is around 250-300kHz (I bought it as bulk, no datasheet was provided). I will try to increase Rt anyway.

Comment: I suspect it is also so I would definitely look at lowering the inductance.

Comment: What should be the current/frequency rating of the lower inductace? I've tried with a 270uH inductor rated for 150 mA, strange things continue to happen (at a 129 kHz switching frequency). Could the IC be damaged?

Comment: "strange things" means nothing to me.

Comment: Output fluctuates between + and -30V at a frequency observable with the multimeter. Drawing about 140mA from the 12V power supply, which is about the saturation current of the inductor. I was expecting to draw much less current, at 85% effiency there should be no need for 140mA if all I need on the output is about 1 mA (currently drawing almost no current, 0.08 mA)

Comment: Is C4 in your circuit really 3.3 pF? It should be more like 10uF.

Comment: Indeed, replaced my output capacitor by a 10 uF, got my desired output.

Comment: @joaocandre cool!