# TINA-TI - trouble with boost converter based on LM5002

Tags: simulation, boost, converter, output, texas-instruments

I wanted to recreate the LM5002 circuit in the TINA-TI program, which I encountered for the first time today. I was inspired by the circuit from the link below:

[LM5002](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157035/excessive-boost-converter-output)

[image: LM5002]

Unfortunately, the effects of the first collision with this program quickly took their toll on me, and the circuit simply does not work properly, when it comes to output voltage.

In fact, I could say that the output voltage is close to the set input voltage instead of being increased. A factor that may be crucial in this case is that I had to import the LM5002 chip into the TINA-TI program, which I did using the Tools-New Macro Wizard function.

I downloaded this model of LM5002 from this manufacturer's link:

[Link to the LM5002 model](https://www.ti.com/product/LM5002?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=app-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe&utm_content=LM5002&ds_k=LM5002&DCM=yes&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAkp6tBhB5EiwANTCx1I02KymlWGVlOnDBXDaCyRaUBd2jIqiBK5bZqMnmFRwDUyP8UJMsixoCs_0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Is it possible that I am making some mistake in running the circuit here?

Link to my file:
[LM5002.TSC](https://easyupload.io/yp22dh)

Comment: `I could say that the output voltage is close to the set input voltage instead of being increased.` that's because there's no switching. So the output will see one diode drop (D2's fwd drop) less than the input voltage.  Make sure the EN pin has enough voltage to start the switching, and RT resistance (R3) is a proper value.

Comment: Thank you for your response! According to the documentation, the EN pin should have a voltage greater than 1.26 V to start switching. Unfortunately, in my circuit, manipulating R1, R2 or even R3 does not change the output voltage value in any way. So I am increasingly concerned about the operation of the LM5002 model that I uploaded to TINA-TI.